# Using Python to Read Rows of CSV Files With Column Content containing Comma

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to parse this CSV and print out the various columns separately.

However my code is having difficulty doing so possibly due to the commas in the addresses, making it hard to split them into 3 columns.

How can this be done?

**Code**

```
with open("city.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        print row.split(',')
```

**Result**

```
['original address', 'latitude', 'longitude\n']
['"2 E Main St', ' Madison', ' WI 53703"', '43.074691', '-89.384168\n']
['"Minnesota State Capitol', ' St Paul', ' MN 55155"', '44.955143', '-93.102307\n']
['"500 E Capitol Ave', ' Pierre', ' SD 57501"', '44.36711', '-100.346342\n']
```

**city.csv**

```
original address,latitude,longitude
"2 E Main St, Madison, WI 53703",43.074691,-89.384168
"Minnesota State Capitol, St Paul, MN 55155",44.955143,-93.102307
"500 E Capitol Ave, Pierre, SD 57501",44.36711,-100.346342
```

Comment: and this is why you should always use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module (or `pandas`)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to parse the file, I would recommend using [Pandas Library](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_csv("city.csv")
```

which gives you a data frame that looks like this in iPython notebook.
[image: resulting data frame]

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `csv` module

```
import csv

with open("city.csv") as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f):
    for row in csv_reader:
        print row
```